# DIY String Encryption

Tags: java, cryptography

I was asked to make a String encryption utility without using encryption API. I basically had to come up with my own encryption methodology! the program was to be able to encrypt a string and decrypt a string and to of course make it nearly impossible for anyone to figure out what the encrypted string says!

I would really love to once again get some advice and suggestions regarding my code! I know it is not fast and could indeed be faster but that wasnt the main focus in this case!

This question is related to [String Encryption](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138612/string-encryption)
which is a previous post made by me regarding this question. I was advised to make another question for another round of reviews so here it goes. I try to follow nearly all of the recommendations given by the community and this is the end result.

The question is now. would you consider this encryption method to be safe? meaning: is it hard to break the encryption without knowing the keys and patterns used behind it? why and why not?

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * <h1>String Encrypter</h1>
 *
 * This programs allows you encrypt a string and store as a byte array.
 * the program provides a simple encryption set of methods which make use of
 * scrambling/adding/replacing/swapping/ the core structure of the string.
 * The encrypted message is the store as byte array object which can be sent through sockets
 * or stored locally. In order to be able to view the content of the string the object
 * must be passed through the decrypt method of this program which will format and reconstruc the
 * string to it's original state.
 *
 * If the message is infiltrated while stored as an encrypted byte array whether if it is traveling
 * through a socket or store locally on a system. the thief wont be able to see
 * the content of the message without the key used by this class
 *
 * @author Eudy Contreras
 * @version 1.1
 * @since 2016-08-16
 */
public class StringEncrypter {

    private final static Charset format = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    private final static char[] plain =
        {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H',
         'I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
         'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X',
         'Y','Z','Ö','Ä','Å','0','1','2',
         '3','4','5','6','7','8','9',' ',
         ',','?','.','!'};

    private final static char[] key   =
        {'D',' ','F','G','H','Ä','U','J',
         'A','L','Z','Å','N',',','P','Q',
         'W','S','T','Ö','.','V','R','X',
         'Y','M','!','B','O','4','6','1',
         '8','3','2','9','0','5','7','E',
         'C','?','I','K'};

    private final static char[] added  =
        {'L','3','5','G','0','Ä','1','0',
         'A','D','9','Å','N','C','0','Y',
         'W','S','8','Ö','4','V','4','1',
         'Q','7','K','6','O','3','6','X',
         '8','3','2','9','0','5','7'};

    private final static String[] byte_Plain =
        {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"};

    private final static String[] byte_Key =
        {"8","0","5","4","9","6","1","3","7","2"};

    private final static Map<Character, Character> plain_Map;
    static
    {
        plain_Map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        for(int i = 0; i<plain.length; i++){
            plain_Map.put(plain[i],key[i]);
        }
    }

    private final static Map<Character, Character> key_Map;
    static
    {
        key_Map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        for(int i = 0; i<plain.length; i++){
            key_Map.put(key[i],plain[i]);
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> plain_Byte_Map;
    static
    {
        plain_Byte_Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<byte_Plain.length; i++){
            plain_Byte_Map.put(byte_Plain[i],byte_Key[i]);
        }
    }

    private final static Map<String, String> key_Byte_Map;
    static
    {
        key_Byte_Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<byte_Plain.length; i++){
            key_Byte_Map.put(byte_Key[i],byte_Plain[i]);
        }
    }
    /**
     * This values determined the swap indexes at which the swapping methods
     * will operate.
     */
    private final static int  swap_index_1 = 2;
    private final static int  swap_index_2 = 6;
    private final static int  swap_index_3 = 4;
    private final static int  swap_index_4 = 3;

    /*
     * The higher the number the more random characters will be added to the encryption.
     * The number set here will affect the performace of the application. The higher the
     * number the lower the performance will be but the more populated with random characters
     * he encryption will be.
     */
    private final static int  max_additions = 6;

    /*
     * The index in which the actually code character will be added too
     * the index must be a number between 0 and max_additions-1.
     */
    private final static int  insertion_index = 2; 

    /**
     * Method used for encrypting a string. The String passed through
     * this method will be encrypted and returned as byte array.
     * The string will go through a series of encryption and obsfuscation
     * method in order to assure that the contents of the string are kept
     * private static and secure.
     *
     * @param message String message which you wish to encrypt.
     * @return Returns the string given string as an encrypted byte array.
     */
    public static byte[] encrypt(String message){
        return encrypt(message,null,null,null);
    }
    /**
     * Method used for encrypting a string. The String passed through
     * this method will be encrypted and returned as byte array.
     * The string will go through a series of encryption and obsfuscation
     * method in order to assure that the contents of the string are kept
     * private and secure.
      * This method allows the input of a custom key set to be used
     * by this program in replacement of the originals. The key must contain all letters of the
     * swedish dictionary as well as a space character represented as
     * a character with a space in between and the standard comma sign.
     *
     * <h1>Knowing the key used by this program is not enough in order
     * to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * @param message String message which you wish to encrypt.
     * @param new_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key. The key set must
     * be 44 characters long and cannot contain duplicates. If the key is
     * not 44 characters long it will simply be ignore and not used. The key
     * must contain the standard comma, period, question mark, exclamation mark
     * as well as the space chararcter ' '.
     * @return Returns the string given string as an encrypted byte array.
     */
    public static byte[] encrypt(String message,char[]new_Key){
        return encrypt(message,null,new_Key,null);
    }
    /**
     * Method used for encrypting a string. The String passed through
     * this method will be encrypted and returned as byte array.
     * The string will go through a series of encryption and obsfuscation
     * method in order to assure that the contents of the string are kept
     * private and secure.
     * This method allows the input of a custom character set and a key set to be used
     * by this program in replacement of the originals. The character sets passed through
     * this constructor cannot contain any duplicates.
     * <p>
     * <h1>The character set and the key set must be
     * of equal lenghts and neither the character set nor the key may have repeating elements.
     * Every element found in the character set must be present in the key set and most preferably
     * at a different index<h1>
     * <p>
     * <h1>Knowing either the chararcter set or the key used by this program doest not garantee
     * the ability to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * @param message String message which you wish to encrypt.
     * @param new_CharSet : The new character set to be passed as a new chararcter set. The character
     * set cannot contain duplicates.
     * @param new_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key. The key set must contain
     * all the characters present in the character set and cannot contain duplicates
     * @return Returns the string given string as an encrypted byte array.
     */
    public static byte[] encrypt(String message, char[] new_CharSet, char[]new_Key){
        return encrypt(message,new_CharSet,new_Key,null);
    }
    /**
     * Method used for encrypting a string. The String passed through
     * this method will be encrypted and returned as byte array.
     * The string will go through a series of encryption and obsfuscation
     * method in order to assure that the contents of the string are kept
     * private and secure.
     * This method allows the input of a custom character set, key set and Byte key to be used
     * by this program in replacement of the originals. The character sets passed through
     * this constructor cannot contain any duplicates.
     * <p>
     * <h1>The character set and the key set must be
     * of equal lenghts and neither the character set nor the key may have repeating elements.
     * Every element found in the character set must be present in the key set and most preferably
     * at a different index<h1>
     * <p>
     * <h1>Knowing either the chararcter set or the key used by this program doest not garantee
     * the ability to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * The byte key must contain 10 unique digits with numbers
     * from 0 to 9 in any desired order.
     *
     * <h1>Knowing the byte key used by this program is not enough in order
     * to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * @param message String message which you wish to encrypt.
     * @param new_CharSet : The new character set to be passed as a new chararcter set. The character
     * set cannot contain duplicates.
     * @param new_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key. The key set must contain
     * all the characters present in the character set and cannot contain duplicates
     * @param new_byte_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key.
     * The key set mus be 10 characters long and cannot contain duplicates.
     * @return Returns the string given string as an encrypted byte array.
     */
    public static byte[] encrypt(String message, char[] new_CharSet, char[]new_Key, String[] new_byte_Key){
        setCharset_setKey_setByteKey(new_CharSet,new_Key,new_byte_Key);

        String cypher = addRandom(message).toString();

        byte[] encryption = cypher.getBytes(format);

        byte[] swapped_Bytes = revertBytes(EncryptionUtils.toByteObject(encryption));

        return swapBytes(swapped_Bytes);
    }
    /**
     * Method used for decrypting a string in the form
     * of a encrypted byte array. The array will go through a series
     * of decryption methods in order to uncover the orignal content
     *
     * @param encryption :byte array containing the encrypted string.
     * @return :Returns a decypted string.
     */
    public static String decrypt(byte[] encryption){
        return decrypt(encryption,null,null,null);
    }

    /**
     * Method used for decrypting a string in the form
     * of a encrypted byte array. The array will go through a series
     * of decryption methods in order to uncover the orignal content.

     * This method allows the input of a custom key set to be used
     * by this program in replacement of the originals. The key must contain all letters of the
     * swedish dictionary as well as a space character represented as
     * a character with a space in between and the standard comma sign.
     *
     * <h1>Knowing the key used by this program is not enough in order
     * to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * @param encryption :byte array containing the encrypted string.
     * @param new_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key. The key set must
     * be 44 characters long and cannot contain duplicates. If the key is
     * not 44 characters long it will simply be ignore and not used. The key
     * must contain the standard comma, period, question mark, exclamation mark
     * as well as the space chararcter ' '.
     * @return Returns a decypted string.
     */
    public static String decrypt(byte[] encryption, char[] new_Key){
        return decrypt(encryption,null,new_Key,null);
    }

    /**
     * Method used for decrypting a string in the form
     * of a encrypted byte array. The array will go through a series
     * of decryption methods in order to uncover the orignal content.
     *
     * This method allows the input of a custom character set and a key set to be used
     * by this program in replacement of the originals. The character sets passed through
     * this constructor cannot contain any duplicates.
     * <p>
     * <h1>The character set and the key set must be
     * of equal lenghts and neither the character set nor the key may have repeating elements.
     * Every element found in the character set must be present in the key set and most preferably
     * at a different index<h1>
     * <p>
     * <h1>Knowing either the chararcter set or the key used by this program doest not garantee
     * the ability to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * @param encryption :byte array containing the encrypted string.
     * @param new_CharSet : The new character set to be passed as a new chararcter set. The character
     * set cannot contain duplicates.
     * @param new_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key. The key set must contain
     * all the characters present in the character set and cannot contain duplicates
     * @return Returns a decypted string.
     */
    public static String decrypt(byte[] encryption, char[] new_CharSet, char[]new_Key){
        return decrypt(encryption,new_CharSet,new_Key,null);
    }
    /**
     * Method used for decrypting a string in the form
     * of a encrypted byte array. The array will go through a series
     * of decryption methods in order to uncover the orignal content.
     *
     * This method allows the input of a custom character set, key set and Byte key to be used
     * by this program in replacement of the originals. The character sets passed through
     * this constructor cannot contain any duplicates.
     * <p>
     * <h1>The character set and the key set must be
     * of equal lenghts and neither the character set nor the key may have repeating elements.
     * Every element found in the character set must be present in the key set and most preferably
     * at a different index<h1>
     * <p>
     * <h1>Knowing either the chararcter set or the key used by this program doest not garantee
     * the ability to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * The byte key must contain 10 unique digits with numbers
     * from 0 to 9 in any desired order.
     *
     * <h1>Knowing the byte key used by this program is not enough in order
     * to decode the content of the strings encrypted by this program!</h1>
     * <p>
     * @param encryption :byte array containing the encrypted string.
     * @param new_CharSet : The new character set to be passed as a new chararcter set. The character
     * set cannot contain duplicates.
     * @param new_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key. The key set must contain
     * all the characters present in the character set and cannot contain duplicates
     * @param new_byte_Key :The key to be passed as a new replacement key.
     * The key set mus be 10 characters long and cannot contain duplicates.
     * @return Returns a decypted string.
     */
    public static String decrypt(byte[] encryption, char[] new_CharSet, char[]new_Key, String[] new_byte_Key){
        setCharset_setKey_setByteKey(new_CharSet,new_Key,new_byte_Key);

        byte[] unswapped_Bytes = revertBytesBack(EncryptionUtils.toByteObject(unSwapBytes(encryption)));

        List<String> list  = EncryptionUtils.fromStringToList(new String(unswapped_Bytes, format),", ");

        EncryptedMessage unScrambled = removeRandom(list);

        String decyphered = revertSubstitution(unScrambled);

        return decyphered;
    }

    private static void setCharset_setKey_setByteKey(char[] new_CharSet, char[]new_Key, String[] new_byte_Key){
        if(new_Key!=null && new_CharSet!=null && new_Key.length == new_CharSet.length){
            key_Map.clear();
            plain_Map.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i<new_CharSet.length; i++){
                key_Map.put(new_Key[i],new_CharSet[i]);
                plain_Map.put(new_CharSet[i], new_Key[i]);
            }
        }
        else if(new_Key!=null && new_CharSet==null && new_Key.length==plain.length){
            key_Map.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i<key.length; i++){
                key_Map.put(new_Key[i],plain[i]);
            }
        }
        if(new_byte_Key!=null && new_byte_Key.length==byte_Plain.length){
            key_Byte_Map.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i<byte_Plain.length; i++){
                key_Byte_Map.put(new_byte_Key[i],byte_Plain[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * Method used to swapp the elements of the input array.
     * The elements will be swapped using 4 nested loops with
     * different swap indexes. The elements are swapped around
     * millions of times
     */
    private static char[] swapCharacters(char[] chars){
        for(int i1 = 0; i1<chars.length-swap_index_1; i1++){
            char temp = chars[i1];
            chars[i1] = chars[i1+swap_index_1];
            chars[i1+swap_index_1] = temp;

            for(int i2 = 0; i2<chars.length-swap_index_2; i2++){
                char temp2 = chars[i2];
                chars[i2] = chars[i2+swap_index_2];
                chars[i2+swap_index_2] = temp2;

                for(int i3 = 0; i3<chars.length-swap_index_3; i3++){
                    char temp3 = chars[i3];
                    chars[i3] = chars[i3+swap_index_3];
                    chars[i3+swap_index_3] = temp3;

                    for(int i4 = swap_index_4; i4<chars.length; i4++){
                        char temp4 = chars[i4];
                        chars[i4] = chars[i4-swap_index_4];
                        chars[i4-swap_index_4] = temp4;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return chars;
    }
    /*
     * Method used to swapp the elements which were previously swapped
     * by the swapCharacters method back to their original index. The swap
     */
    private static char[] revertCharacterSwap(char[] chars) {
        for (int i1 = chars.length - (swap_index_1+1); i1 >= 0; i1--) {

            for (int i2 = chars.length - (swap_index_2+1); i2 >= 0; i2--) {

                for (int i3 = chars.length - (swap_index_3+1); i3 >= 0; i3--) {

                    for (int i4 = chars.length - 1; i4 >= (swap_index_4); i4--) {
                        char temp4 = chars[i4];
                        chars[i4] = chars[i4 - swap_index_4];
                        chars[i4 - swap_index_4] = temp4;
                    }

                    char temp3 = chars[i3];
                    chars[i3] = chars[i3 + swap_index_3];
                    chars[i3 + swap_index_3] = temp3;
                }

                char temp2 = chars[i2];
                chars[i2] = chars[i2 + swap_index_2];
                chars[i2 + swap_index_2] = temp2;
            }

            char temp = chars[i1];
            chars[i1] = chars[i1 + swap_index_1];
            chars[i1 + swap_index_1] = temp;
        }
        return chars;
    }
    /*
     * Method which swaps the elements match to the character set
     * whith the correspondnt key element. The method will also create
     * an array holing information about the case of each character. The method
     * will also perform a character swap with a call to the swapCharacters method. After
     * the process is completed this method will return a set of characters holding the
     * coded message along with a set of characters holding case information. The
     * two are divided by a special sequence of symbols in order to distinguish the
     * the two. The return message will then be passed further for further encryption.
     */
    private final static EncryptedMessage applySubstitution(char[] message) {

        char[] case_Binary = new char[message.length];
        char[] code_Message = new char[message.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(message[i])) {
                case_Binary[i] = '1';
            }
            if (Character.isLowerCase(message[i])) {
                case_Binary[i] = '0';
            }
            code_Message[i] = Character.toUpperCase(message[i]);
            if(plain_Map.containsKey(code_Message[i])){
                code_Message[i] = plain_Map.get(code_Message[i]);
            }
        }
        return new EncryptedMessage(swapCharacters(code_Message),case_Binary);
    }

    /*
     * Method which reverts the character substitution performed by the
     * applySubstitution. It does this by reverting the pattern in which the substitution
     * was made. This will separate and analyze the message along with the case data
     * and once this is done it will also peform a call to the revertCharacterSwap method
     * in order to also unswap the order of the characters to their original state.
     * Once the substitution and the character swap has been reversed it wil further
     * analyze case data determine the case of each character. Upon completion it
     * will return the decrypted message.
     */
    private final static String revertSubstitution(EncryptedMessage message) {

        char[] code_Message = revertCharacterSwap(message.getCharMessage());
        char[] case_Message = message.getCharCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < code_Message.length; i++) {
            if(key_Map.containsKey(code_Message[i])){
                code_Message[i] = key_Map.get(code_Message[i]);
            }
            if (case_Message[i] == '1') {
                code_Message[i] = Character.toUpperCase(code_Message[i]);
            }
            if (case_Message[i] == '0') {
                code_Message[i] = Character.toLowerCase(code_Message[i]);
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(code_Message);
    }

    /*
     * Method used to further increases the obsfuscation level of the message by adding
     * random numbers and characters to the body of the already encrypted message. This
     * is done at key places of the message in order to allow the substraction of the oginal
     * version of the encryption witout having to deal with the extrac characters and numbers
     * added by this function. The function a
     * the process can then be reversed with an additional key.

     */
    private final static LinkedList<String> addRandom(String code) {
        LinkedList<String> cypherList = new LinkedList<>();
        EncryptedMessage case_and_code = applySubstitution(code.toCharArray());

        String code_message = case_and_code.getMessage();
        String code_case = case_and_code.getCase();

        for (int index = 0; index < code_message.length(); index++) {
            cypherList.add(EncryptionUtils.getRandomString(max_additions,code_message.charAt(index),insertion_index));

        }

        cypherList.addFirst("" + (EncryptionUtils.getRandomInterval(100,999)));
        cypherList.add(String.valueOf(code_case) + EncryptionUtils.getRandom(10));

        return cypherList;


    }
    /*
     * Method used to remove all previously added obsfuscation elements. The method
     * will loop through the values of a given list and it will filter the orignal's
     * message values into their respective char arrays, one holding the code and the
     * othe holding the case related data.
     */
    private final static EncryptedMessage removeRandom(List<String> cypher_List) {

        StringBuilder string_Builder = new StringBuilder();

        char[] case_message = new char[cypher_List.size() - 2];
        char[] code_message = new char[cypher_List.size() - 1];

        for (int index = 0; index < cypher_List.size() - 1; index++) {
            if (index >= 1)
                string_Builder.append(String.valueOf(cypher_List.get(index).toCharArray()[insertion_index]));
            if (index < case_message.length)
                case_message[index] = cypher_List.get(cypher_List.size() - 1).toCharArray()[index];
        }

        code_message = string_Builder.toString().toCharArray();

        return new EncryptedMessage(code_message, case_message);
    }

    /*
     * Method used to further encrypt the message by replacing the
     * first first digit of every value on every index of the byte array
     * except for indexes that hold a negative value. This method converts
     * the byte value to string which is than formated and casted back to
     * a byte. A modification can be perform that may allow each index to
     * be replace using a numerical value check!
     */
    private final static Byte[] replaceBytes(Byte[] bytes) {
        Byte[] temp_Bytes = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bytes.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp_Bytes.length; i++) {
            if (Integer.toString(temp_Bytes[i]).charAt(0) != '-') {
                String temp_String = String.valueOf(temp_Bytes[i]);
                String new_Value = plain_Byte_Map.get(Integer.toString(temp_Bytes[i]).substring(0, 1))+ temp_String.substring(1);
                temp_Bytes[i] = Byte.valueOf(new_Value);
            }
        }
        return temp_Bytes;
    }
    /*
     * Method used to revert the previously replaced bytes back to
     * to normal. The byte array will go throug an identical procedure
     * as the one performed in the replace bytes method in order to
     * give each byte index the original value of the first index.
     */
    private final static Byte[] revertByteReplacement(Byte[] bytes) {
        Byte[] temp_Bytes = Arrays.copyOf(bytes, bytes.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < temp_Bytes.length; i++) {
            if (Integer.toString(temp_Bytes[i]).charAt(0) != '-') {
                String temp_String = String.valueOf(temp_Bytes[i]);
                String new_Value = key_Byte_Map.get(Integer.toString(temp_Bytes[i]).substring(0, 1))+ temp_String.substring(1);
                temp_Bytes[i] = Byte.valueOf(new_Value);
            }
        }
        return temp_Bytes;
    }
    /*
     * Method used to swapp the elements of the input array.
     * The elements will be swapped using 3 nested loops with
     * different swap indexes. The elements are swapped around
     * millions of times.
     */
    private final static byte[] swapBytes(byte[] bytes){
        for(int i1 = 0; i1<bytes.length-swap_index_1; i1++){
            byte temp = bytes[i1];
            bytes[i1] = bytes[i1+swap_index_1];
            bytes[i1+swap_index_1] = temp;

            for(int i2 = 0; i2<bytes.length-swap_index_2; i2++){
                byte temp2 = bytes[i2];
                bytes[i2] = bytes[i2+swap_index_2];
                bytes[i2+swap_index_2] = temp2;

                for(int i3 = swap_index_4; i3<bytes.length; i3++){
                    byte temp3 = bytes[i3];
                    bytes[i3] = bytes[i3-swap_index_4];
                    bytes[i3-swap_index_4] = temp3;
                }
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    /*
     * Method used to swapp the elements which were previously swapped
     * by the swapBytes method back to their original index. The swap
     */
    private final static byte[] unSwapBytes(byte[] bytes){
        for (int i1 = bytes.length - (swap_index_1+1); i1 >= 0; i1--) {
            for (int i2 = bytes.length - (swap_index_2+1); i2 >= 0; i2--) {
                for (int i3 = bytes.length - 1; i3 >= (swap_index_4); i3--) {
                    byte temp3 = bytes[i3];
                    bytes[i3] = bytes[i3 - swap_index_4];
                    bytes[i3 - swap_index_4] = temp3;
                }
                byte temp2 = bytes[i2];
                bytes[i2] = bytes[i2 + swap_index_2];
                bytes[i2 + swap_index_2] = temp2;
            }
            byte temp = bytes[i1];
            bytes[i1] = bytes[i1 + swap_index_1];
            bytes[i1 + swap_index_1] = temp;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    /**
     * Reverses the byte array for further increase obfuscation.
     */
    private final static byte[] revertBytes(Byte[] encryption){
        Byte[] byte_Array = encryption;

        List<Byte> byte_List = Arrays.asList(byte_Array);

        Collections.reverse(byte_List);

        return EncryptionUtils.toPrimitives(replaceBytes(byte_Array));
    }
    /**
     * Reverses the byte array to its original state
     */
    private final static byte[] revertBytesBack(Byte[] encryption){
        Byte[] byte_Array = encryption;

        List<Byte> byte_List = Arrays.asList(byte_Array);

        Collections.reverse(byte_List);

        return EncryptionUtils.toPrimitives(revertByteReplacement(byte_Array));
    }
    /**
     * <h1>Encrypted Message</h1>
     *
     * This class is used as a wrapper containing both
     * the code of the actual string and case data of
     * said string.
     *
     * @author Eudy Contreras
     * @version 1.1
     * @since 2016-08-16
     */
    private static class EncryptedMessage{
        private final String code_message;
        private final String case_message;

        public EncryptedMessage(char[] codeX, char[] caseX){
            this.code_message = String.valueOf(codeX);
            this.case_message = String.valueOf(caseX);
        }
        public final String getMessage(){
            return code_message;
        }
        public final String getCase(){
            return case_message;
        }
        public final char[] getCharMessage(){
            return code_message.toCharArray();
        }
        public final char[] getCharCase(){
            return case_message.toCharArray();
        }
    }
    /**
     * <h1>Encryption Utility</h1>
     *
     * This class contains various functions used by the program.
     *
     * @author Eudy Contreras
     * @version 1.1
     * @since 2016-08-16
     */
    private static class EncryptionUtils{
        /*
         * Method which converts an Object byte array to a primitive type.
         */
        private static byte[] toPrimitives(Byte[] byte_Object){

            byte[] bytes = new byte[byte_Object.length];

            int i = 0;
            for(Byte byte_Objects : byte_Object)bytes[i++] = byte_Objects;

            return bytes;
        }
        /*
         * Method which converts a primitive byte array to an object byte array.
         */
        private static Byte[] toByteObject(byte[] byte_prime) {
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[byte_prime.length];

            int i = 0;
            for (byte byte_Primes : byte_prime) bytes[i++] = byte_Primes;

            return bytes;
        }
        /*
         * Method which prints the content of a byte array.
         */
        private static String printBytes(byte[] binaryEncription){
            return new String(binaryEncription, format);
        }
        /*
         * Method which splits a string at a given character sequence
         * and returns List made out of all the sections.
         */
        private static List<String> fromStringToList(String list, String sequence) {
            return Arrays.asList(list.split(sequence));
        }
        /*
         * Method which generates a secure random within a
         * given range.
         */
        private static int getRandom(int value){
            SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
            return rand.nextInt(value);
        }
        /*
         * Method which generates a secure random within a
         * given interval.
         */
        private static int getRandomInterval(int minValue, int maxValue) {
            SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
            return rand.nextInt(maxValue + 1 - minValue) + minValue;
        }
        /*
         * Method which returns a random string of the specified
         * lenght containing a non random element located at the given index. 
         */
        private static String getRandomString(int length, char code, int index){
            char[] randomString = new char[length];
            for(int i = 0;i<length; i++){
                randomString[i] =added[getRandom(added.length)];
                if(i==index){
                    randomString[i] = code;
                }
            }
            return String.valueOf(randomString);
        }
        /*
         * Method which returns a radom string of the specified
         * lenght.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static String getRandomString(int length){
            char[] randomString = new char[length];
            for(int i = 0;i<length; i++){
                randomString[i] =added[getRandom(added.length)];
            }
            return String.valueOf(randomString);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      EncryptionUtils.getRandomString(10,'Ö',1);
        long encrypt_start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        byte[] encryption = StringEncrypter.encrypt("What is up!!, Not much why??");
        long encrypt_end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Encryption speed: "+(encrypt_end_time - encrypt_start_time)+ " Milliseconds");

        System.out.println("Actual encrypted message:");
        System.out.println("////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(EncryptionUtils.printBytes(encryption));
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");

//      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encryption));
        long decrypt_start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(StringEncrypter.decrypt(encryption));
        long decrypt_end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Decryption speed: "+(decrypt_end_time - decrypt_start_time)+ " Milliseconds");
    }
}
```

I know the code is long but I tried to documented well and structure it to make easy to read. I sincerely appreciate all your time and I hope my question is well formulated and on topic.

Comment: Please do not edit your code after you have received an answer on it as it invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8")`, there is a predefined constant called `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. Use that instead.
- Constants are written in UPPERCASE_LETTERS. This is a Java convention, and you should follow it.
- Do not make all methods `public`, but only those that the users of this encryption class should see. Basically, there should be only two public methods: `byte[] encrypt(String text, String key)` and `String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String key)`. That way, you don't have to write so much repeated documentation.
- Do not use `under_scores` in Java identifiers (except for `UPPER_CASE` constants).
- Proofread for typos and incomplete sentences: swapp, othe, first first, he, and many more.
- Instead of `Integer.toString(temp_Bytes[i]).charAt(0) != '-'`, just write `temp_Bytes[i] < 0`.
- In the `revertByteReplacement` method, the expression `Integer.toString(temp_Bytes[i]).substring(0, 1))+ temp_String.substring(1)` is way too complicated. Just use `String.valueOf(temp_Bytes[i])` instead.
- In `revertBytes`, don't confuse *revert* (to undo something) and *reverse*. In general, your code should be easy to read and understand. That means, use well-established words to describe what your encryption algorithm does.
- The method `printBytes` doesn't print anything. Change its name.
- In `main`, do not print raw encrypted bytes as a string. They could end up being invalid UTF-8 sequences, resulting in the replacement character to be printed. Format the encrypted bytes using Base64.
- Write a test method where you ensure that you can encrypt an example string and decrypt it again to the same string.
- The Javadoc for the `new_Key` parameter doesn't describe the requirements well. The key must be 44 characters long, but is it ok to write the required punctuation plus 39 Korean characters?
- The `swapCharacters` method seems rather useless to me. When I pass `[J, H, Å, Å, P, C, E, R, P, S, Å, G]` to it, it returns `[Å, Å, P, C, E, R, P, S, Å, G, J, H]`, so the only thing that changed during these *millions of times* of swapping is that the array is rotated by two positions. Why do millions of swapping then?

Comment: Freaking Awesome!! That is perfect! thank you for all the advice! I will do my best to follow them and implemented on my future code. cheers and thank you for all your time. =)

Comment: it is weird about the swapCharacters! check this out:                          WVB9RF,TD38L?PE6HZSÖQXK4.M ÄJO1!5Y7Å0INGC2AU                                                result of the base character array

Answer (score 5):

In encryption, never provide a default key. People will use it without thinking further, and the default key will be known to anyone using your code.

When you are given a wrong key, do not silently ignore it. Throw an exception instead. Combined with the default key above, this would lead to no encryption at all.

Even better, make it impossible to provide a wrong key. Instead, accept a password and compute a correct key from this password. For example, like this:

```
/* Choose a fixed SecureRandom algorithm to be able to decrypt the ciphertext later on. */
SecureRandom getSha1Prng() {
  try {
    return SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
  }
}

String generateKey(String password) {
  SecureRandom random = getSha1Prng();
  random.setSeed(password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

  List<Integer> keyCodePoints = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö0123456789".codePoints().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  Collections.shuffle(keyCodePoints, random);

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (Integer codePoint : keyCodePoints)
    sb.appendCodePoint(codePoint);
  return sb.toString();
}

@Test
public void test() {
  assertEquals("l7nw1y9uz5jqk03vfoåmpäis84hdbegtöxr62ac", generateKey(""));
  assertEquals("06o3yd2äz7belfö9h8ucjisgmpqkrwa4tx5ånv1", generateKey("1"));
  assertEquals("afms5qånye7r9wxö1tcj8i3k4ou0hg6l2vzäpdb", generateKey("2"));
  assertEquals("åö7nwib26zlhk9g3amy4s5fvxec1pqjod8ä0utr", generateKey("3"));
  assertEquals("8nqlseph5fat1vöki4x03cyuz6gbmwä7doå9j2r", generateKey("4"));
}
```

Check that when you change a single character in the plaintext or in the key, the encrypted message looks totally different.

Comment: Hey! This is really helpful i will definitely do this! I wonder the approach i should i take once the user is no longer providing his/her own key! Within what context do i return the key! Maybe i print it to the console or a pop up window since everything is statically done. thank you very much for your recommendation 1+

Comment: Updated the code, since it didn't compile before. (I had written it from my head.)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I had followed the recommendations you gave earlier and I this is the updated version. Would you consider it safe or do you see ways to bypass the encryption? =)

Comment: I now generate random keys which are attached to a password

Comment: I cant seem to be able to update the Version but here is a snippet! https://gist.github.com/Darkyec/4916356e503742001bc331b19e6b9536

Comment: @EudyContreras If you wish, you can post a followup question with the changes.  However, you may wish to wait a couple days too see if you get any more answers on this question.

Comment: @Hosch250 Ok thank you for the comment. I will then gladly post a follow up question at a later time before my code is to be submitted. I would really like to be reviewed by some peers before than.

Comment: Sure thing.  Also, just be sure to not roll your own encryption for anything important--let the professionals handle that.

Comment: @haha thanks for the advice. I am not planing to use it at all I just want to learn the concepts of encrypting data =D. It is good exercise and a school assignment I am taking way too serious.

Comment: Just in case you are using this code and your techer complains about the use of SHA1PRNG (since that is a well-established algorithm), you can use a plain `Random` instead of the `SecureRandom` and seed it using `password.hashCode()`. This really weakens your encryption, since there will be only 2^32 possible keys, but it will help you to break the encryption, just in case that this is the next lesson. ;) The random algorithm used here is just for shuffling, therefore it must be predictable, in contrast to other random numbers.

Comment: Once again thank you for all your help and engagement and advice. Cheers buddy =)